# How to Manage Environment Variables for Continuous Deployment

Tags: automation, continuous-integration, chef-infra, puppet, ansible

So, a common practice these days is to put connection strings & passwords as environment variables to avoid their being placed into a file.  This is all fine and dandy, but I'm not sure how to make this work when trying to set up a continuous deployment workflow with some configuration management tool such as Salt/Ansible or Chef/Puppet.

**Specifically, I have the following questions in environments using the above mentioned configuration management tools:**

1. Where do you store connection strings/passwords/keys separate from codebases?

   - Do you keep those items in a code-repo of some type (git, etc.)?
   - Do you use some structure built-in to your tool?
2. How do you keep those same items secure?
3. Do you track changes/back-up these items, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

In Chef you can

1. store passwords or API tokens in either [encrypted data bags](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_data_bags.html#encrypt-a-data-bag) or using [chef-vault](https://github.com/Nordstrom/chef-vault). They are then decrypted while chef does the provisioning (with encrypted data bags using a shared secret, with chef-vault using the existing PKI of Chef client).
2. set environment variables when calling external software using the `environment` parameter of e.g. the [execute resource](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_execute.html).
3. *not sure, what to write here* -- I'd say you don't really manage them. This way you set the variables only for the command that needs it, not e.g. for the whole chef run.

Comment: Encrypted data bags is the way to go.

Comment: I'd say chef-vault is the way to go ;-)

Answer (score 0):

With puppet, the preferred way is probably to store the secrets in Hiera files, which are just plain YAML files. That means that all secrets are stored on the master, separate from the manifest files.

Comment: But that's still in VCS, isn't it?

Comment: Not necessarily. At my place we have the modules in a VCS that's use by all environments, and specific hieradata for each environment.

Answer (score 0):

[truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org) virtual encrypted disks are cross-platform and independent of tooling. Mount it read-write to change the secrets in the files it contains, unmount it and then commit/push the encrypted disk image into version control. Mount read-only for automation.

Answer (score 0):

ansible-vault can be used to encrypt sensitive data files. A CI server like Jenkins however is not the safest place to store access credentials. If you add Hashicorp Vault and Ansible Tower/AWX, then you can provide a secure solution for several teams.